# Angular UI Router: <a ui-sref="state1"> tag needs href to activate link

Tags: angularjs

Following documentation from [angular/ui-router @ github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

```
body
  .unstyled
    a(ui-sref="state1") State 1
    a(ui-sref="state2") State 2
```

State1 State2 display as text not as links, as the href is not included in the tag. Is adding href necessary for using Angular-UI-Router? or is there a workaround? Problem with adding 'href' is then the entire routing will need to be managed for that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon correct inclusion of

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
    })
    .state('state2.list', {
      url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
        }
      })
    });
```

Angular will include a `href='#'` dynamically.

*[code from Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)